# gdal.py as part of bat script in windows 7

Tags: geoserver, gdal, pyscripter, importerror

I need to run the following bat file from a MS4W shell which has gdal_retile.py as the final option. I have added C:\ms4w\python\gdal to my pythonpath but within a pyscripter shell I can not import gdal or gdal_retile.py

**Without a linux box is there a way to get the final step to work?**

**CODE of P.bat File**

```
mkdir -p %2\%3
gdal_translate -expand rgba -of GTiff -a_srs EPSG:3857 -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES %1 %2\%3\%3_translated.tif
gdalwarp -multi --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 500 -wm 500 -r near -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "TILED=YES" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" -srcnodata 255 -dstnodata 255 -overwrite %2\%3\%3_translated.tif %2\%3\%3_rebuilt.tif
mkdir -p %2\%3\pyramids
gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps 2048 2048 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -targetDir %2\pyramids %2\%3\%3_rebuilt.tif

Pause
```

**OUTPUT of process**

> GDAL, mapserv, mapcache, PROJ, and shapelib dll paths set GDAL_DATA
>   path set GDAL_DRIVER_PATH set PROJ_LIB set CURL_CA_BUNDLE set
>   C:\Users\georgec\Desktop>P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer
>   _Creation\4Band_translated_pyramid\p.bat P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Outp
>   ut\8_Bit_TIF_Colourmap_RS\TRC_WC_WaterResource_Catchment\TRC_WC_WaterResourceCat
>   chment.tif
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\4Ban
>   d_translated_pyramid wc
>
> C:\Users\georgec\Desktop>mkdir -p
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Ras
>   ter_Layer_Creation\4Band_translated_pyramid\wc
>
> C:\Users\georgec\Desktop>gdal_translate -expand rgba -of GTiff -a_srs
>   EPSG:3857
>   -co TILED=YES -co BIGTIFF=YES P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Output\8_Bit_TI
>   F_Colourmap_RS\TRC_WC_WaterResource_Catchment\TRC_WC_WaterResourceCatchment.tif
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\4Band_translate
>   d_pyramid\wc\wc_translated.tif Input file size is 19844, 26300
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
>
> C:\Users\georgec\Desktop>gdalwarp -multi --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 500
>   -wm 500 -r n ear -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "TILED=YES" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" -srcnodata 255 -dst nodata 255 -overwrite
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Cr
>   eation\4Band_translated_pyramid\wc\wc_translated.tif
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Sy
>   mbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\4Band_translated_pyramid\wc\wc_rebuilt.tif
>
> Creating output file that is 19844P x 26300L. Processing input file
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Cr
>   eation\4Band_translated_pyramid\wc\wc_translated.tif. Using band 4 of
>   source image as alpha. Using band 4 of destination image as alpha.
>   0...10...20...30...40.**ERROR 2: Out of memory allocating 130520448 bytes for Unif iedSrcDensity mask**. ..50..
>   C:\Users\georgec\Desktop>mkdir -p
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Ras
>   ter_Layer_Creation\4Band_translated_pyramid\wc\pyramids A subdirectory
>   or file -p already exists. Error occurred while processing: -p.
>
> C:\Users\georgec\Desktop>gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 4 -ps
>   2048 2048 - co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -targetDir
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbol
>   ogy\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\4Band_translated_pyramid\pyramids
>   P:\2012\183_
>   TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\4Band_translated_pyramid\wc
>   \wc_rebuilt.tif Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\ms4w\python\gdal\gdal_retile.py", line 38, in 
>       import gdal ImportError: No module named gdal
>
> C:\Users\georgec\Desktop>Pause Press any key to continue . . .

I also get the following Error

> ERROR 2: Out of memory allocating 130520448 bytes for Unif iedSrcDensity mask

Comment: How much memory you got on C:\?

Comment: 930GB on C and 350gb on D (this is free space off 1TB drives) and they are running 16GB RAM on XEON 3.4GHz. Windows 7, 65-bit.

Comment: What about the P: drive

Comment: 1.72TB free...these are network drives with plenty of space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in the OSGEO4W shell and gdal_retile.py works fine. However I am getting out of memory errors on larger files in the 2nd stage gdal_warp.

See new question if you want to help! [VSIMalloc3() and UnifiedSrcDensity mask errors when running gdal_warp in OSGEO4w shell](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41899/vsimalloc3-and-unifiedsrcdensity-mask-errors-when-running-gdal-warp-in-osgeo4w)