# VSIMalloc3() and UnifiedSrcDensity mask errors when running gdal_warp in OSGEO4w shell

Tags: gdal, osgeo

This is related to [gdal.py as part of bat script in windows 7](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41810/gdal-py-as-part-of-bat-script-in-windows-7)

I am getting

> ERROR 2: VSIMalloc3(): Out of memory allocating 854522136 bytes.
>
> ERROR 2: Out of memory allocating 119813400 bytes for
>   UnifiedSrcDensity mask.

I am running a XEON 3.4GHz. Windows 7, 64-bit with 16GB RAM. 930GB on C and 850gb on D (this is free space off 1TB drives) and network drives with 1.72TB free.

The command I am running in a bat file is

```
gdalwarp -multi --config GDAL_CACHEMAX 500 -wm 500 -r near -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -co "TILED=YES" -co "BIGTIFF=YES" -srcnodata 255 -dstnodata 255 -overwrite %2\%3\%3_translated.tif %2\%3\%3.tif > %2\%3\2_%3_warp_log.txt
```

where %1=input tif, %2=output directory, %3=file name

In this case the input file is

> Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF Files:
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\4Band_translated_pyramid\z_zones\z_zones_translated.tif
>   Size is 411096, 298318 Coordinate System is: PROJCS["WGS 84 /
>   Pseudo-Mercator",
>       GEOGCS["WGS 84",
>           DATUM["WGS_1984",
>               SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
>                   AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
>               AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
>           PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
>           UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
>           AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
>       PROJECTION["Mercator_1SP"],
>       PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
>       PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],
>       PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
>       PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
>       UNIT["metre",1,
>           AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
>       EXTENSION["PROJ4","+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs"],
>       AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]] Origin = (15825753.321902087000000,-1808723.335397920600000) Pixel Size =
>   (1.000002861523879,-1.000001022298165) Metadata:   AREA_OR_POINT=Area 
>   DataType=Thematic Image Structure Metadata:   INTERLEAVE=PIXEL Corner
>   Coordinates: Upper Left  (15825753.322,-1808723.335) (142d 9'54.58"E,
>   16d 2' 4.35"S) Lower Left  (15825753.322,-2107041.640) (142d
>   9'54.58"E, 18d35'33.74"S) Upper Right (16236850.498,-1808723.335)
>   (145d51'29.19"E, 16d 2' 4.35"S) Lower Right
>   (16236850.498,-2107041.640) (145d51'29.19"E, 18d35'33.74"S) Center
>   (16031301.910,-1957882.488) (144d 0'41.89"E, 17d19' 5.07"S) Band 1
>   Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red   Mask Flags: PER_DATASET
>   ALPHA  Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green   Mask Flags:
>   PER_DATASET ALPHA  Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
>   Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA  Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte,
>   ColorInterp=Alpha

The pipe of the gdal_warp command gives

> Creating output file that is 411096P x 298318L. Processing input file
>   P:\2012\183_TownPlanning_Symbology\Working\Raster_Layer_Creation\4Band_translated_pyramid\z_zones\z_zones_translated.tif.
>   Using band 4 of source image as alpha. Using band 4 of destination
>   image as alpha. 0

so the process is failing before even 10% is complete and fails about 1h after processing starts.

I am just setting up a linux box to try this out on but is there something I can tweak in windows to get this to work?

best,

--- UPDATE 1

Part of the issue is with the cache and wm switches. Removing these helps but the larger process still crash. http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalWarp